# Symfony 3 - pattern causes login problems with guard authenticator

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I was trying to add authenticator, which should be responsible only for access to path /Abc, and by default other security areas secured by default authenticator.

As long as I add pattern line `pattern: ^/Abc` into my security.yml everything works fine. I can login and logout. The user is authenticated with
Token class PostAuthenticationGuardToken and Firewall abc.

When I add line `pattern: ^/Abc` I can not login anymore (into /Abc area). After I submit my login form application reload into path login_abc

**security.yml**

```
security:
   firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        abc:
            anonymous: ~
            pattern: ^/Abc
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - abc_authenticator
            form_login:
                login_path:     login_abc
                check_path:     login_abc
                remember_me:    false

            logout:
                path:   logout_abc
                target: main_index

        default:
            anonymous: ~
            pattern: ^/(?!Abc)
            form_login:
                always_use_default_target_path: false
                login_path:     login
                check_path:     login
                remember_me:    false

                logout:
                    path:   logout
                    target: main_index




   access_control:
            - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
            - { path: ^/login_abc, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
            - { path: ^/Abc, roles: [ROLE_ABC] } 
            - { path: ^/Work, roles: [ROLE_WORK, ROLE_WORK2] }
            - { path: ^/Home, roles: [ROLE_HOME] }
```

**abcAuthenticator.php**

```
namespace AppBundle\Security;

use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\AbstractGuardAuthenticator;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry as Doctrine;


class abcAuthenticator extends AbstractGuardAuthenticator {

    const ACCESS_DENNIED = "Access dennied";

    /**
     * @var \Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface
     */
    private $router;

    /**
     * @var Doctrine
     */
    private $doctrine;


    /**
     * abcAuthenticator constructor.
     */
    public function __construct(RouterInterface $router, Doctrine $doctrine) {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
    }

    public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null) {
        $url = $this->router->generate('login_abc');
        return new RedirectResponse($url);
    }

    public function getCredentials(Request $request) {
        if ($request->getPathInfo() != '/login_abc' || !$request->isMethod('POST')) {
            return;
        }

        return array(
            'cardToken' => $request->request->get('_cardToken'),
        );

    }

    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider) {
        try {
            try {
                $user = $this->doctrine->getRepository(User::class)->findOneByCardToken($credentials['cardToken']);
                if (is_null($user)) {
                    throw new UsernameNotFoundException();
                }
                return $userProvider->loadUserByUsername($user->getUsername());
            } catch (UsernameNotFoundException $e) {
                throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException(self::ACCESS_DENNIED);
            }

        }
        catch (UsernameNotFoundException $e) {
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException(self::ACCESS_DENNIED);
        }
    }

    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user) {
        return true;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception) {
        $url = $this->router->generate('login_abc');
        return new RedirectResponse($url);
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey) {
        $url = $this->router->generate('abc_panel');
        return new RedirectResponse($url);
    }

    public function supportsRememberMe() {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Authenticator is of course registered as a service.

I have no idea what is wrong. Pls help.

Comment: I found the solution. The pattern in abc should be pattern: ^/(Abc|login_abc), and in default no pattern should be present.

Answer (score 0):

In your `getCredentials()` method, you appear to only allow login if you go to the URL `/login_abc` (URL, not a route name) - but only allowing the guard to be run on the URL `/Abc`.

Using multiple firewalls is complex - you may find things easier to have a single firewall and then allow multiple authentications to run, until you have a success (based on the URL, and then any username, password/tokens etc), and then the rest would be skipped.

Comment: Thanks @Alister for your help. The problem is, when I add pattern in my security.yml function getCredentials() is not even reached